# Flex column height:100% inside 100vh height container

Tags: css, flexbox

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hxknmzfd/).

I have a flex layout with `flex-direction:column` inside a container with `height: 100vh`. My flex layout container (the blue one) has to take the full height (`height:100%`) of the main container.

Given this context now I want to avoid flex elements overflow on the right when the viewport height is too small to contain all the elements.

So I want that all the viewport is blue and all my red elements inside the blue stay into a column.

I tried to set `min-height:100vh` , it works for letting have all my items in column but awkwardly my blue flex layout container no loger takes the full 100% height.

I can't change the html structure.

Answer (score 1):

In `.search-form {...}` replace `height: 100%;` with `min-height: 100%;` so that it's allowed to grow larger than 100%.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/n8egcq7g/)

Answer (score 1):

> Given this context now I want to avoid flex elements overflow on the
>   right when the viewport height is too small to contain all the
>   elements.
>
> So I want that all the viewport is blue and all my red elements inside
>   the blue stay into a column.

In the flex container (`.flex-row`) change `flex-wrap: wrap` to `flex-wrap: nowrap`.

```
.flex-row {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    /* flex-wrap: wrap; REMOVE */
    flex-wrap: nowrap; /* NEW */
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/hxknmzfd/2/

> [**`flex-wrap`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap)
>
> The CSS `flex-wrap` property specifies whether flex items are forced
>   into a single line or can be wrapped onto multiple lines.

Comment: Nice solution that uses modern techniques, but one remark would be that when the parent is shrunk in height, the content is pushed outside both at the top and at the bottom of the parent, instead of just at the bottom as most people'd probably expect.

Comment: @klaar, yes, I noticed that. When the parent (blue) shrinks small enough, the red boxes overflow the container. That's because the font size is fixed at 18px. So the container can shrink all the way to 0, but the red boxes cannot because of the 18px content in each box. One method to minimize the overflow would be to use `vh` for the font size: http://jsfiddle.net/hxknmzfd/4/

Comment: Or another one is to adapt `justify-content` to another value using media queries.

Comment: And another would be to change `height: 100%` to `min-height: 100%` in the parent +1 :-) Using both your answer and mine is probably the optimal solution.

Comment: @klaar, another thing to note is that when the screen shrinks small enough to where the red boxes overflow, the page is already too small to read. So accessibility overrides this issue anyway.

Comment: Ah yes, I wasn't looking at it from a broader perspective than just testing it in the fiddle.